# Labview VISA timeout, aborting issue

Tags: labview, visa, gpib

I am developing a program to remotely access the multimeter through GPIB. I am using visa read function to obtain measurement values and convert string of values to numerical values. At proper Visa timeout setting, program is able to execute without any problem. However, if it is not enough timeout, program is not able to capture values and it is not able to scan from string at the Read buffer. Same thing happen when I try to abort the program during its running. The only thing that help is to  restart the Labview.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *if it is not enough timeout*. How long does the multimeter take to return a reading and what VISA timeout settings have you tried?

Comment: at highest nplc the time for multimeter to take a reading is about 4 sec. When I set visa timeout to 3 sec, program crashes, and i get random string from the reading buffer. When I rerun the program with more than enough timeout (100sec) the program still give out an error. The error clears only after I reopen labview. This problem also occurs after I interrupt the program by pressing abort button (round red) while its running.

Comment: If the device can take 4 s to return a reading then your timeout should probably be something like 6 or 8 s - if you let the reading time out before the message has been fully received then you will get bad data or no data. If you get errors, what are the actual error codes? For troubleshooting GPIB communications you may get more help on the NI forums though.

Comment: I don't think I will an answer to this question on forums. My main concern is, if there is a way for me to clear the error without having to restart labview. clearly there is something which resets the program but I want it include it in my program. do you have any suggestions

Comment: It's hard to help with "an error" if you can't tell us what the error code is. I don't have much experience with GPIB but there are lots of people who read and post on the NI forum who do.

Comment: @Rokkibalboa, I'd say you should try closing the VISA connection on error, which prevents the infamous green computer icon from disallowing you to use the device again. You can even open a new .vi and add a "VISA Close" block, wire in a VISA control, and close the connection separately.